# Problems when using SUM as it counts duplicate ID rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I am learning how to use `Group By` in SQL Server and I am trying to write a Query that would let me get all the information from `Tickets` in a table in numbers after `inner joining` it with other table `BY SELECTED DATE`.

My tables are like the following:

The first table gives me a more detailed description of items sold in each ticket:

```
 DATE               | Ticket_ID | Items_Sold | Item_Name      | Client_ID
2018-04-17 00:00:00      1           3          Watch              1
2018-04-17 00:00:00      1           2          Snapnack Hat       1       
2018-04-17 00:00:00      2           1          Arizona Tea        1    
2018-04-17 00:00:00      2           2          Wristband          1
2018-04-18 00:00:00      3           2          Pants              1
2018-04-18 00:00:00      3           2          Wristband          1
2018-04-18 00:00:00      4           1          Pants              1
2018-04-18 00:00:00      4           1          Wristband          1
```

The Second table gives me a basic description of what is in each ticket and the total paid.

```
 DATE_Sale                  | Ticket_ID | Employee_ID | Total | Client_ID
 2018-04-17 00:00:00              1          1          150       1
 2018-04-17 00:00:00              2          1          60        1             
 2018-04-18 00:00:00              3          2          200       1
 2018-04-18 00:00:00              4          2          100       1
```

So if i want to know what happened between `2018-04-17 00:00:00` and `2018-04-18 00:00:00` and group it by Client_ID and by DATE

The result I want is the following one:

```
DATE_Sale             | Tickets | Total_Items_Sold | Total_Paid | Client_ID
2018-04-17 00:00:00        2             8             210          1      
2018-04-18 00:00:00        2             4             300          1
```

The problem is that when i use the 'inner join' to get the total items sold all sums are giving me the wrong results as it seems they are adding from duplicate rows as Table 1 contains multiple rows for the same Ticket_ID and the Same Date

My current query is the following one:

```
SELECT B.DATE_Sale, 
       B.Client_ID, COUNT(B.Ticket_ID) as Tickets, 
       SUM(A.Items_Sold) as Total_Items_Sold, 
       SUM(B.Total_Paid) as Total_Paid
FROM Table_A as A
INNER JOIN Table_B as B
ON A.Client_ID = B.Client_ID
AND B.DATE_sales = A.DATE_Sales
Group by B.DATE_sales, A.Client_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `subquery` with *correlation* instead

```
select a.DATE as DATE_Sale, COUNT(DISTINCT a.Ticket_ID) as Tickets,
       sum(a.Items_Sold) as Total_Items_Sold,
       (select sum(Total) from Table_B 
        where DATE_Sale = a.DATE and 
              Client_ID = a.Client_ID) as Total_Paid, a.Client_ID
from Table_A as a
group by a.DATE, a.Client_ID;
```

In other way, you can use `subquery` and do the `join`

```
select a.DATE as DATE_Sale, COUNT(DISTINCT a.Ticket_ID) as Tickets,
          sum(a.Items_Sold) as Total_Items_Sold,
          b.Total_Paid, a.Client_ID   
from Table_A as a
inner join (select DATE_Sale, Client_ID, 
                   sum(Total) as Total_Paid
             from Table_B 
             group by DATE_Sale, Client_ID) as b 
ON b.DATE_Sale = a.DATE and 
   b.Client_ID = a.Client_ID
group by a.DATE, a.Client_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(select DATE_Sale,client_id, count(distinct ticket_id ) as tickets, sum(items_sold) as total_items_sold
 from table_a group by client_id, DATE_Sale),
 cte2 as
(select client_id,DATE_Sale, count(distinct ticket_id) as tickets, sum(total) as total_paid
         from table_b group by client_id, DATE_Sale) 
select a.DATE_Sale_is,a.tickets, a.total_items_sold, b.total_paid,a.client_id from cte a join cte2 b
on a.client_id = b.client_id
and a.DATE_Sale_is = b.DATE_Sale
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with two levels of aggregation, because that captures how the data should be populated.  The first level is at the ticket level and the second at the summary level you want:

```
select t1.date, count(*) as num_tickets, sum(num_items) as num_items,
       sum(t2.total_paid) as total_paid
from (select date, ticket_id, client_id, count(*) as num_items, 
      from table1
      group by date, ticket_id, client_id
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ticket_id = t2.ticket_id and
        t2.date_sale = t1.date and t2.client_id = t1.client_id
group by t1.date;
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` is a often a short-cut for avoiding multiple levels of aggregation.  In this case, you really need the aggregation and using lots of subqueries/CTEs to get around the issue just makes the query more complicated than it needs to be.